# How to write this for loop conditions in Verilog design correctly?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I want to write a module in Verilog that outputs the same 32-bit input at positive clock edge. However, I have some trouble with the loop conditions.
[image]

Comment: in verilog there is no `+=` operator. you would need `i = i+1` instead. Or you can switch to system verilog. Also you have a bunch of other syntactic errors in port declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module if_id (
  input             clk
 ,input      [31:0] in
 ,output reg [31:0] out
);

 always@(posedge clk)
   out <= in;

endmodule
```

you don't need to write looping code if your intention is to register a 32bit value . But if u need to write it in array mode u need to use `genvar` variable in your code. By the way `int` isn't supported in verilog variants . migrate to System-verilog for more number of data types.

Comment: Then in which cases the for loop is used?

Comment: Please go through `genvar` variable in verilog u will get basic understanding of `for` loop variable usage context in hardware languages